# Publishing error with file copy

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that I have been trying to deploy to a specific folder locally, but I keep getting an error when trying to copy over the System.Windows.Interactivity.zip. The exact error message is:

> Error 2   Copying file ClientBin\System.Windows.Interactivity.zip to
>   obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\ClientBin\System.Windows.Interactivity.zip
>   failed. Could not find file
>   'ClientBin\System.Windows.Interactivity.zip'.

I do have a project that has a reference to this dll, but the project compiles just fine. Any ideas why I'm getting this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an old zip file and added to the destination folder. Couldn't figure it out but it works this way